# Connect to database in network drive

Tags: c#, sql, networking

I am a newbie to SQL Server and .net. Please let me know if my question is not clear before down voting.

I am working on a Windows application with C#. I should give option to users to connect to a `.mdf` file on a network drive. On my machine, I have Windows and SQL Server authentication. Users have SQL authentication hence I should use userid and pwd. Myself and users work on that network drive, read/write/modify. We pretty much share documents, add and delete docs from network drive.

Here is the designer

[image: UI design]

I will choose the SQL Server database `.mdf` file which is located in network drive and then do test connection. For Test Connection this is the code

```
 string sTemp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionStringShare"];

 string connectionString = sTemp.Replace("{AppDir}", txtDB.Text.Trim());

 using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
          try
          {
              objSqlConnection.Open();
              objSqlConnection.Close();
              MessageBox.Show("Connection is successfull");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message.ToString());

          }
}
```

This is the connection string

```
<add key="connectionStringShare" 
     value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TableSQLExpress;AttachDBFilename={AppDir};Integrated Security=SSPI;user id=sa;password=pwd;" />
```

Here is the error message I got

> Directory lookup for the file "S:\zrep\TableSQLExpress.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   Cannot attach the file 'S:\zrep\TableSQLExpress.mdf' as database 'TableSQLExpress'.

I changed connection string and tried also tired using windows authentication. No luck. Let me know if I need to provide any additional details. Since I am newbie to this field please give me detailed answer. I am glad to find this group. Thanks for everyone who looked into this.

Comment: Does it work if you use the UNC path instead of the drive letter?

Comment: If you have a **server-oriented** environment anyway - why bother fiddling around with `.mdf` files and such? Just have a centrally located SQL Server machine, create your databases there **on the server**, and connect to the server and the databases using the **logical database name** only - don't mess around with `.mdf` files and attaching them and stuff like that - waaaaay to complicated and error-prone - without any real benefit.

Comment: @marc_s I know it sounds strange but we don't have server-oriented environment.

Comment: @DStanley Not sure how to get UNC path, will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: But you do have *network drives* --> so you have a **network** - so it would be **no problem at all** to put up a single dedicated machine as your server. Seriously - **do NOT** fiddle around with `.mdf` files - **especially** not from network shares! This is a **recipe for disaster!**

Comment: @marc_s I know it would be much easy if we have single dedicated machine, but there is lot of conspiracy and our team is trying to get one. I am looking for some temporary solution until we get server machine (not sure when it happens though!!). I was left with no choice than to play with mdf files in network drive.

Comment: I can only repeat myself: fiddling around with `.mdf` on a **network share** is a **guaranteed recipe for DISASTER**. Just imagine what happens if you attach a `.mdf` and in the middle of writing back a transaction, the network connection goes away...... **DON'T DO IT!**. Period. Save yourself all that grief!

Comment: @marc_s OK. Sounds scary, I will look into other alternatives. Thanks for your heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

When you use server-based SQL Server (i.e. *Microsoft SQL Server Express*) you are unable to share database file via network drive, it is by design. Even if you override default SQL Server behavior with a switch and enable UNC paths for databases, your data will be corrupted by multiple server instances trying to use single database MDF file. If you need to host database in serverless environment (using only a network drive), you may opt to *Microsoft SQL Server Compact* (*SQL Server CE*) edition. But be aware that in such case only one user will be able to access database file at the same time (exclusive locking -> low performance). Plus *SQL Server CE* does not have stored procs.