# How can C# Windows form application data source use UNC path to read the MDF file

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection

I am having below connection string:
sdb.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=" + @dbPath + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

My application is going to run in PC A and the physical .MDF file will be store in PC B. PC A as well as PC B has the SQL server setup.

When the .MDF file is on PC A and the @dbpath is pointing the PC A, database can be open and records can be read. This applied to PC B as well so the point is when reading from local drive and not UNC path, database can be read.

When application is running on PC A and the @dbpath is trying to access PC B .MDF file, no connection can be establish.

Folder access level is open to everyone so no authentication will be require.

@dbpath = C:\database\testing.mdf is working but not @dbpath = \100.10.10.5\c$\database\testing.mdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to database in network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490722/connect-to-database-in-network-drive)

Comment: The database owns the mdf file with different credentials than the user.  You should always use the database name and not the mdf filename.  If you are connecting to a database in a remote PC that change the Data Source to SQL Server in remote PC : "Data Source=PCB\SQLEXPRESS; ..."